# People should provide how much experience they have in a language/topic in their question/answer

Tags: feature-request

On like a scale of 1 to 10 or in experience years, the person can provide about how much experience they have with the language, so the OP or answerer can see it.

Points really don't do any justice here.  This will help for answers and asking and what type of experience level to assume.

A lot of times people ask the dumbest questions. If people answering can see that the person has 1 week experience, it's a big difference than 6 months, etc.

Just throwing it out there.

Comment: Yea you can downvote this all you want, but when you're the one out there thinking people already know the language but don't and trying to figure it out, it makes a difference.

Comment: This whole thing reads like a big "it makes a difference because I said so." You've provided absolutely no reasoning to back up your claims or support your request.

Comment: @animuson  Go to the `jQuery` section, you'll see what I mean.

Comment: No. We won't. That's why we disagree. Because you have presented absolutely no evidence or anything of logical value.

Comment: @bjb568 No we wont what?  Not everyone is a mindreader like you apparently are.

Comment: @animuson I think what you're trying to say is *I would rather not change the system we worked so hard to build*  You have people out here copy/pasting stuff from other people asking people how it works when they don't even know how to write an if statement. If you know this person has no experience, and asking a higher level question, it might be an easy way to trigger the fact that the person needs to have more experience before getting to that level, and help them in the right path.  Didn't know that political bs resides in a place like this asking for `logical evidence` , lol, open ur eyes

Comment: @ZeeTee And what stops them from just saying they have more experience than they do? It's pretty easy to judge someone's experience level just from the words they use and the way they interact with others. No silly rating required.

Comment: @animuson Nothing, I assume, however, why would someone need to lie about this?  If they really want the best help, they would let people know how much experience they have. It's not only about the people who don't know a thing and trying to pass off like they do, I'm sure they would actually be more inclined to disclose their true experience level in the language.  Knowing where the person's strengths are language wise, helps.

Comment: You can't just add in something like a 1-10 scale rating system and expect it to work exactly as you intended it to work. Not everyone is going to look at it as a "how much experience I have" indicator. Some will try to use it as a difficulty indicator, and some will look at it and just think "if I say I have more experience then I'll attract other people with more experience."

Comment: Then in time frame.  Years/Months/Weeks.  `How much experience do you have in this language?`   From an answerer and asker myself, I can find value in this, and I'm sure many other people will too.

Comment: The fact that every 10 minutes there is someone with 10 points trying to get an answer about something that they have absolutely no clue about.

Comment: I still don't see your point, or the value in knowing how much experience they have. Does their being new to a language somehow make an unacceptable question into an acceptable one?

Comment: @bjb568 You want some proof?  Let me find the question I had dealt with and let me tell you what happened.  This guy posts a question about adding a captcha in classic asp.  He says it's not working.  I go find out he doesn't even have IIS installed and has no clue how to do anything. He just doing this for a job he picked up and even offered to pay me to do it, and when i asked how much he said $5.  Are you kidding me?  The code he had posted was written by someone way more experienced and he trying to get someone off here to do the job for him.

Comment: If I knew this guy has absolutely no experience, I would've told him to learn classic asp instead of leaching off people on here to do your job for you.

Comment: @ZeeTee Re your anecdote: What do you want us to do about it?

Comment: It wouldn't be per question, it would be profile based, would just show up in the question with that particular tag. A way for people to tell others how much experience they have, because they don't always remember to mention it in their post. It would recognize which tags you post to and then ask when you come back `Would you like to share your experience level in the tags your affiliated with?` totally optional, but I would find it useful, I am a user.

Comment: Meh - I've never used java but have a bronze badge for it:)

Comment: @ZeeTee Yeah, sometimes it's difficult to tell, but it's rare.  It's actually quite funny when a question contains a wall of complex code but, when asked to 'printf out the indices in the findEntry func loops to see if they run over the ends', they have no clue whatever on how to do that, or even what it means:)

Comment: I particularly enjoy the increasingly-frantic screeching and wailing as the submision deadline approaches and they cannot get anyone to fix the half-finished and undebugged code they copied from some other student.  Then it all suddenly goes quiet as they fail their course:)

Comment: How much exp do you think this person has? I came to this thread right after dealing with this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77909212/im-having-trouble-subtracting-in-c-sharp

Comment: @BartMcEndree approximately 9

Answer (score 8):

We can generally gauge the experience level from the question text itself, and the profile activity, within a reasonable margin of error. Someone with years of experience in a topic is highly unlikely to ask the same kind of questions someone who just started learning about the topic would ask.

Prompting the asker to fill out a form indicating their exact experience will only lead to bad user experience and doesn't add any value to the site. It forms an extra unnecessary hurdle to the registration process or the use of the site, just to gather information that is otherwise easily gathered over time as the user participates actively.

> A lot of times people ask the dumbest questions.

Admittedly, it can be frustrating to see questions about the simplest of things that you deem obvious. But questions from the curious are not dumb. There are slow learners, and then there are fast learners. As a community, we have to be patient with the former group while also catering to the latter.

We already have several safeguards in place to protect the sites from being bombarded with questions about the same thing over and over again. But it works on the assumption that something being asked has already been asked before, and it's not perfect. That's also why we also have the flagging system (duplicate flags).

> when you're the one out there thinking people already know the language but don't and trying to figure it out

Personally I do my best to avoid this by gauging the level of knowledge the asker has and then providing an answer that is as easy to understand as possible for someone of the same level of knowledge.

> Let me find the question I had dealt with and let me tell you what happened.

When you find leechers like this (with evidence of) attempting to milk the system for their own benefit, simply downvote and flag the question, and move on. There really is no need to waste your energy on someone like that. You can focus it on answering other questions from genuine askers.

Comment: *Generally* seems to be less and less often.  It's not really the leachers, it's the people that try to ask questions that they shouldn't be.

They shouldn't be trying to do something without learning the pre-requisites first, and this place should teach that, if they truly concerned about the element of learning, and not just a quick fix.  From an answerers perspective, it makes it hard to know if you can just give the short answer, or give the long answer so the person can truly learn the concept behind the code.

Comment: I see. If you get the feel that the asker may not have pre-requisite knowledge, you can ask questions in the comments section for clarification. That's one way to better gauge the experience level. Of course, if the asker seems impatient and wanting a quick answer than responding to your clarification requests, you know what to do.

Comment: Many times I want to just say you should try learning this before you even get here.  Maybe a flag on a question that says user lacks pre-requesite knowledge or something might suffice

Comment: I doubt such a flag will even be considered as flags are for questions, not for users. If you want to say something like that, please do it. But **do it politely**. Never try to put down a user who is over-enthusiastic about a new toy they discovered and want to tinker with. Be encouraging and guiding to the user, telling them where and how they can get up to speed in using the technology.